# Will creating many components slow down my application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So far, I have the following routes for the toy's category:

http://localhost:3000/#/mb/to/disney/disney frozen

Below is the route for my disney brand. Just imagine how many disney characters there are. How about Marvels, Transformers, etc.

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/disney moana, component DisneyMoanaComponent },
  { path: '/disney frozen', component: DisneyFrozenComponent },
  { path: '/disney movies', component: DisneyMoviesComponent },
  { path: '/disney', component: DisneyHomeComponent },
  { path: '/', component: DisneyHomeComponent }
])
```

This route is just for my disney brand in the toy category. For my google brand, is shorter:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/google daydream view', component: DayDreamViewComponent },
  { path: '/daydream view', component: DayDreamViewComponent },
  { path: '/pixel', component: PixelComponent },
  { path: '/chromecast', component: ChromecastComponent },
  { path: '/google home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/google chromecast', component: ChromecastComponent },
  { path: '/google pixel', component: PixelComponent }, 
  { path: '/google', component: GoogleHomeComponent },
  { path: '/', component: GoogleHomeComponent }
])
```

Since I have too many components, should I design my app and display my characters page based on the route param like below?

```
http://localhost:3000/#/mb/to/disney/disney/frozen
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. If you create immutable components, you can optimize the change detection strategy so that it skips whole sub-trees: https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c#.ieu9a4o1y

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link you provided.